# Как правильно транскрибировать Ford Falcon?

Tags: транскрипция

подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно транскрибировать на русский язык название марки автомобиля Ford Falcon? "Форд Фалкон", "Форд Фалькон", "Форд Фэлкон" и т.д.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что "Неоднословные названия (марка и модель автомобиля), написанные кириллицей, пишутся через дефис, при этом все части наименования пишутся с прописной буквы: «Лада-Приора», «Тойота-Королла», «Рено-Меган»…" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само слово "falcon" по историческим причинам транскрибируется по разному, в зависимости от конкретной области применения.
Название ракет обычно транскрибируют "Фалкон", известный пестицид - "Фалькон", фамилии людей могут быть и "Фэлкон", хотя изначальное английское слово одно и то же: "falcon".
Т.е. в каждом случае это просто вопрос традиций.

Из всего перечисленного, Ford Falcon, на мой взгляд, ближе всего к ракете, поэтому я бы выбрал вариант **"Форд Фалкон"**.